# Delegate methods of UIScrollView inside a UIWebView not called for horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIWebView` which has both horizontal and vertical content off the visible screen.

I set my controller to be the delegate of the `UIWebView`'s `UIScrollView`, and noticed that when I scroll horizontally, `scrollViewDidScroll`, `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` are not called. They are called when I scroll vertically.

update:
I also noticed there's no scroll bar when I scroll horizontally, but there is one when I scroll vertically. Also, scrolling horizontally doesn't bounce, even with `alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES`.

I am using a `white-space: nowrap` CSS style in my UIWebView. Could this be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this.

Along with the `white-space: nowrap` styles, I also had `overflow: auto`. Removing that, achieved the same effect I wanted and now the horizontal scrolling works as I wanted.